# JQuery Globalizations devuelve mal los decimales

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

buen día gente.

Estoy aquí para molestarlos, porque llevo varios días peleando con este asunto y no puedo solucionarlo..

Les comento.. estoy intentando convertir ciertos números ingresados en decimales con el formato correspondiente a mi país. Pero Globalize devuelve los valores de modo incorrecto.

Lenguaje jQuery.

Por ejemplo

```
var a = Globalize("es-AR").parseNumber('3,15'); // 3.15
```

En este caso, **a** debería contener el número **3,15**

```
var a = Globalize("es-AR").parseNumber('3.15'); // 315
```

En este caso, también realiza mal la conversión, ya que debería devolver **3,15** y no 315

Tengo los cldr

```
numberingSystems.json
numbers.json
```

¿alguien sabe a que pueda deberse esto?, La verdad me está volviendo loco!

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

en la página oficial de jquery tienes un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer 
te dejo el enlace: https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#decimal
lo único que te harán falta jquery, jquery ui y globalize

Comment: Deberías poner el ejemplo aquí mismo, porque los links no son bien recibidos por un rollo de que pueden caer y ya no estar disponible para futura documentación.

Comment: Ya los tenía agregados, logré solucionarlo el día de hoy, el problema era que en el viewstart estaba importando el bundle de jquery, y dentro de el documento cshtml lo hacía de nuevo, al parecer, de ahí partio el error. Muchas gracias por la ayuda